# Не работает плагин xZoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Плагин не работает плавно на моб версии,то есть не так как должен. А на айфоне вообще не работает, вот силка чтоби посмотреть самому https://aleksandr-kalinichenko.github.io/micro/

[image: вот как работает на айфоне]

Comment: Сделайте в виде сниппета или на кодпен минимальное демо без лишних элементов, никто по картинке гадать или разбираться на вашем сайте с канвасом и скриптами не будет (но это не точно) но на первый взгляд не работают события `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove`